# How to compare date.now to specific date that convert to datetime in C#

Tags: c#, date, datetime, datetimepicker, visual-c#-express-2010

I have two textboxes. Textbox1 enable when datetimepicker value same with datetime now & datetime now same with the first date of the month.

And textbox2 enable when datetime now not same with the first date of the month.

I try to make like this, but when I choose the 1st date, it throws an error:

[I try like this but doesn't work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guhfu.png)

```
  private void dateTimePicker1_ValueChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Date == DateTime.Now.Date && DateTime.Now.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(1).Date)
        {
            month_in.Enabled = true;
            sisa.Enabled = false;
        }
        else //if (dateTimePicker1.Value.Date < DateTime.Now.Date || DateTime.Now.Date != Convert.ToDateTime(1).Date)
        {
            month_in.Enabled = false;
            sisa.Enabled = true;
        }

    }
```

Comment: Please read [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Paste your code here. Please don't post screenshots of code.

Comment: Are you trying to do `false` when current month its NOT the month of dateTimePicker?

Comment: @Sankar sorry. I already edited the question and there's the code

Comment: @user8549339 no. i try to do false when the date of dateTimePicker not same with date 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `if` condition, do :

```
DateTime.Now.Day == 1
```

Instead of :

```
DateTime.Now.Date == Convert.ToDateTime(1).Date
```

inorder to check if it is the first day of the month.